# Problema al generar contenido en archivo index.php

Tags: php, html

tengo un archivo crear.php que al ejecutarlo automaticamente crea un archivo index.php todo bien hasta ahi, el problema es que al colocar el contenido del archivo index.php lo genera mal este es mi archivo crear.php

```html
<?php 

$nombre = ($_GET['nombre']);

$archivo= "contador.php";  
$contenido= "<?php
$archivo = 'descargas.txt'; 
$contador = 0; 

$fp = fopen($archivo,'r'); 
$contador = fgets($fp, 26); 
fclose($fp); 

$contador = $contador +1; 

$fp = fopen($archivo,'w+'); 
fwrite($fp, $contador, 26); 
fclose($fp); header('Location: https://laptop-updates.brave.com/download/BYJ606'); 

?>"; 

$fch= fopen('hola/'.$archivo, "w");
fwrite($fch, $contenido);  
fclose($fch);  

header("Location: crear.php?nombre=$nombre");
?>
```

Al momento de revisar el arhivo index.php creado me sale asi y no como yo lo estoy colocando en el archivo crear.php

```html
<?php
contador.php = 'descargas.txt'; 
 = 0; 

 = fopen(contador.php,'r'); 
 = fgets(, 26); 
fclose(); 

 =  +1; 

 = fopen(contador.php,'w+'); 
fwrite(, , 26); 
fclose(); header('Location: https://laptop-updates.brave.com/download/BYJ606'); 

?>
```

y entonces no me esta funcionando, no se que peudo ahcer para que salga bien? gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenta cambiarlo de la siguiente manera.

```
<?php 

$nombre = ($_GET['nombre']);

$archivo= "contador.php";  
$contenido= '<?php
$archivo = "descargas.txt"; 
$contador = 0; 

$fp = fopen($archivo,"r"); 
$contador = fgets($fp, 26); 
fclose($fp); 

$contador = $contador +1; 

$fp = fopen($archivo,"w+"); 
fwrite($fp, $contador, 26); 
fclose($fp); header("Location: https://laptop-updates.brave.com/download/BYJ606"); 

?>'; 

$fch= fopen('hola/'.$archivo, "w");
fwrite($fch, $contenido);  
fclose($fch);  

header("Location: crear.php?nombre=$nombre");
?>
```

Debido al tipo de cadena que estas utilizando si tu imprimes un echo con comillas dobles, es decir, de esta manera

```
$var = 1;    
echo "$var";
```

el resultado que te imprimiria sería 1, en cambio si lo imprimes de esta forma

$var = 1;
echo '$var';

Te imprimira el nombre de la variable, puedes revisar más información de este tema en el siguiente link: https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.types.string.php